# Simple way to derive transpose of a vectorized operation

Tags: matlab, matrix

In a program I'm writing, I have a sub-routine that does some vectorized linear operations (specifically differentiation).  Say for convenience I have defined the following inline function, which approximates a partial derivative from a 3D array:

$$
F = @(X)(X(3:\text{end},:,:)-X(1:\text{end}-2,:,:))/(2h)
$$

This is a linear transformation which would clearly have a matrix representation.  Is there a simple way to derive the index form of its transpose, $F^{T}$?  I would like to avoid building matrices if possible because the array formulation is much cleaner (and I've already implemented it...).  The "interior" grid points seem obvious - the transpose is also a difference operator.  But is there an easy way to see what the boundary terms will be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know of a general way to do this, but it is certainly not generally possible to write the transpose of a given linear operator with such a simple vectorized expression. Consider your example, but applied to a simple 1d vector `x` instead of a 3d array, I will call this function $G(x)$:
`G = @(x) ( x(3:end)-x(1:end-2) )/(2*h)`

- $G$ operates on vectors of length $n$ and returns vectors of length $n-2$
- If I write $G$ as a matrix it is
  $$
  G_{(n-2)\times n} = \dfrac{1}{2h}\left[\begin{array}{c}
  -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0\\
  0 & -1 & 0 & 1 & \dots & 0\\
   &  & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \\
  0 & \dots & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1\\
  \end{array}\right]
  $$
- The transpose of $G$ is
  $$
  G^\intercal_{n\times(n-2)} = \dfrac{1}{2h}\left[\begin{array}{c}
  -1 & 0 & & 0\\
   0 & -1 & & \vdots\\
   1 & 0 & \ddots & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & \ddots & -1 \\
   \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & 0\\
   0 & 0 & & 1
  \end{array}\right]
  $$
- There are a couple obvious ways to write a function for $G^\intercal x$, but none of them quite as simple as the expression for $G$. For example:
  `Gtranspose = @(x) [-x(1:2); x(1:end-2)-x(3:end); x(end-1:end)]/(2*h);`

A primary reason for the difference is the fact that `G` is non-square. What you requested can be done very easily if the operator is square and symmetric or anti-symmetric. As you probably know, a symmetric operator is its own transpose and the negative of an anti-symmetric operator is its transpose. For example, your derivative operator $F$ is very nearly anti-symmetric. If you consider periodic boundary conditions then the operator is symmetric and can be written as

```
H = @(X) [ X(end,:,:) - X(2,:,:); ...
           X(3:end,:,:) - X(1:end-2,:,:); ...
           X(end-1,:,:)-X(1,:,:) ]/(2*h);
```

the transpose is then given by $H^\intercal = -H$ so

```
Htranspose = @(X) [ X(2,:,:) - X(end,:,:); ...
                    X(1:end-2,:,:) - X(3:end,:,:); ...
                    X(1,:,:) - X(end-1,:,:) ]/(2*h);
```

This approach should work for finite differences based on central differences which are always either symmetric (even derivatives) or anti-symmetric (odd derivatives).

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I decided to stop being a wimp and learn how to use Kronecker products for constructing difference matrices.  Sparse matrix multiply ends up being just as fast as indexing anyway, so overall a net benefit.